# click on a dynamically generated div - no ID and class, nested inside a static div using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to call click function using JQUERY on the div containing text "Save as JPEG" . The div with ID= "graph1" is static and all other nested divs are dynamic. The dynamic div containing text has no class or ID.

```
<div id="graph1" class="col-sm-12" style="height: 250px">
    <div class="contianer">
        <div class="convascharttoolbar">
            <div>
                <div>save jpeg</div>
                <div>save png</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `Save as JPEG` your div dont contain this test?will there be instance that no div contain this text also there will be instance that there will be many div with this kind of text?

Comment: This is the working demo https://jsfiddle.net/k3L6e2ca/

Answer (score 4):

> Use [`:contains(TEXT)`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector => *Select all elements that contain the specified text.*

```
$("div:contains('save jpeg')").on("click",function(){
  console.log(this.textContent);
});
```

Comment: how about a div with text `jpegrandomdiv`

Comment: if you click `save png` will this trigger the click?yes? OP wants jpeg only

Comment: For dynamic events: `$("#graph1").on('click', "div:contains('save as jpeg')", function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});` [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/uwoa4nw4/)

Answer (score 1):

**Working Demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  $("#graph1").on('click','div', function() {
    if($(this).text() == "save as jpeg"){
      alert('Div clicked')
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="graph1" class="col-sm-12" style="height: 250px">
  <div class="contianer">
    <div class="convascharttoolbar">
      <div>
        <div>save as jpeg</div>
        <div>save png</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```